# QuickFix engine acceptor and initiator

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

i`m trying to make a quickfix initiator and acceptor connect to each other and just send a heartbeats. But no matter what i try it dont seems to work at all. I read all the documentation avaible but there isnt much and with almost no working examples. I tryed to run the executor that come with the engine but i cant manage to work it aswell. So if anyone can help with any information , books or sample code about this will be great. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What aspect of the Executor sample didn't work? Or could you just not find an Initiator to connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got caught out by the StartTime and EndTime settings. I had it working one day, then the next morning I started it and nothing happened. Went to lunch, came back and it was running. Exactly the same thing happened the next day and it turned out I had this in the session settings:

```
StartTime=12:00:00
EndTime=23:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your [heartbeat time limit](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html) config set for the initiator.

```
HeartBtInt=5
```

Set it to the number of seconds after which a heartbeat message is sent to your acceptor. On receiving the heartbeat message the acceptor will send you back an acknowledgement, an admin message.